# How to get only text part from excel custom formatted cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I have excel column already formatted with both number and text using custom format options in excel.. now i need to get only the text part from that columns.. If i copy paste the column in another cell, it assigns only value.. also when i double click in that cell, it displays only numeric values.. so i can't get the text part..

Sample image column as below.. I need only text values 'nos' , 'PKS' in seperate columns...

[image]

Comment: Use `RegEx` expressions to extract only the string part

Comment: Are all your values similar to the above?

Comment: @QHarr yes...it is similar to above

Comment: @ShaiRado May i know any sample RegEx formula.. because i don't have so much knowledge in excel..

Comment: Based on those examples: `Mid$(activecell.text, instr(activecell.text, " ")+1)` should do it.

Comment: Since the text values are part of the custom format, you will need to write a VBA routine to extract the text portion.  After you've done some research on this, write your routine and post back with either your solution, or your specific problem.  See @Rory comment for a suggestion as to part of your UDF.

Comment: Would Copy/Paste-Value include the text portion of the custom format?

Comment: Now that I'm at a computer, copy/paste-value does not include the text portion of the custom format; in case anyone was wondering.

Answer (score 1):

Very basic attempt, which will fail in some cases of  additional whitespace is

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1,1))
```

For additional white space handling:

```
=RIGHT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32)," ")),LEN(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32)," ")))-FIND(" ",TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(32)," ")),1))
```

Comment: If the cell's format is e.g. `0" PKS"` then no formula will help.

Comment: Sorry what does that mean? If Cell contains 0 PKS?

Comment: It means that the custom cell format is `0" PKS"`. Judging by OP's description it's exactly how the cells are formatted.

Comment: @BrakNicku I am being dense today I'm afraid. So their custom format is what? I don't recognise what 0" PKS" is? I am still relatively new to all this.

Comment: OP said: _when i double click in that cell, it displays only numeric values_. So probably there's a custom formatting. [Link to SO image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWoqE.gif). If you define the custom format as `0" PKS"`, you will achieve exactly what OP is describing.